# What are the performance impacts that Expects(cond) of the GSL imposes on the runtime?

Tags: c++

The CPP Core Guidelines propose to use `Expects(expression)` [to state preconditions](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#i6-prefer-expects-for-expressing-preconditions) and `Ensures(expression)` [to state postconditions](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#i7-state-postconditions) from the [GSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL) in functions.

Example:

```
int area(int height, int width)
{
    Expects(height > 0 && width > 0);            // good
    if (height <= 0 || width <= 0) my_error();   // obscure
    // ...
}
```

What is the performance impact of these macros? 
Is it just as checking the condition with if and then throwing an exception?
Is there a difference between debug and non-debug mode? 
I.e. are the macros also active if the app is built as a release?

I ask because I am thinking about using it as a good practice, i.e. try, if there is not a specific reason against it, just stating possible pre/post conditions (assuming it is not sensible to use different types as parameters) using these macros from the GSL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These macros are defined in the [`gsl_assert`](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/gsl_assert) header.

Here's the relevant code:

```
#define Expects(cond) GSL_CONTRACT_CHECK("Precondition", cond)
```

```
#if defined(GSL_THROW_ON_CONTRACT_VIOLATION)

#define GSL_CONTRACT_CHECK(type, cond)                                                             \
    (GSL_LIKELY(cond) ? static_cast<void>(0)                                                       \
                      : gsl::details::throw_exception(gsl::fail_fast(                              \
                            "GSL: " type " failure at " __FILE__ ": " GSL_STRINGIFY(__LINE__))))

#elif defined(GSL_TERMINATE_ON_CONTRACT_VIOLATION)

#define GSL_CONTRACT_CHECK(type, cond)                                                             \
    (GSL_LIKELY(cond) ? static_cast<void>(0) : gsl::details::terminate())

#elif defined(GSL_UNENFORCED_ON_CONTRACT_VIOLATION)

#define GSL_CONTRACT_CHECK(type, cond) GSL_ASSUME(cond)

#endif // GSL_THROW_ON_CONTRACT_VIOLATION
```

As you can see, it depends on how you choose to handle contract violations. In the first two cases, you will pay the cost of a branch plus either throwing an exception or calling `std::terminate`.

In the case that `GSL_UNENFORCED_ON_CONTRACT_VIOLATION` is defined, the macros will expand to `GSL_ASSUME`:

```
//
// GSL_ASSUME(cond)
//
// Tell the optimizer that the predicate cond must hold. It is unspecified
// whether or not cond is actually evaluated.
//
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define GSL_ASSUME(cond) __assume(cond)
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
#define GSL_ASSUME(cond) ((cond) ? static_cast<void>(0) : __builtin_unreachable())
#else
#define GSL_ASSUME(cond) static_cast<void>((cond) ? 0 : 0)
#endif
```

In that case, the condition might or might not be evaluated depending on the compiler. It can also make your code faster as the compiler might be able to optimize more aggressively thanks to the assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that Expects is slightly against the spirit of C++ (as I perceive this spirit) ... Maybe it would really be good if C++ was more mainstream and Java-like but for me its original idea is to provide maximum performance (sometimes at the cost of less safety/more complexity/lower readability). I think we can obtain both goals without sacrifising performance. For me the solution is quite simple - custom assert (cassert) - that is the fast assert that can be switched on or off for release builds.

Sample implementation (Windows only) :

```
// cassert.h:
#pragma once

// Switch this macro off for maximum performance release builds:
#define __RELEASE_WITH_ASSERTS__

#ifndef cassert

#if defined(_DEBUG) || defined(__RELEASE_WITH_ASSERTS__)
void __cassert(bool val, const char* szFile, int line, const char* szDesc);
#define cassert(a) ((a) ? ((void)1) : __cassert(a, __FILE__, __LINE__, _CRT_STRINGIZE(#a)))
#else
#define cassert(a)
#endif

#endif

// cassert.cpp
#if defined(_DEBUG) || defined(__RELEASE_WITH_ASSERTS__)
void __cassert(bool val, const char* szFile, int line, const char* szDesc)
{
    if (!val)
    {
        std::string sIgnore;
        int mode;

        #if defined(_DEBUG)
        sIgnore = "\n\nIgnore assertion?";
        mode = MB_YESNO;
        #else
        sIgnore = "";
        mode = MB_OK;
        #endif

        char szLine[16];
        _itoa(line, szLine, 10);

        std::string sAssertion = std::string("Assertion failed in file ") + szFile + " at line " + szLine + "\n" + szDesc;
        Log(sAssertion.c_str());

        if (MessageBoxA(NULL, (std::string("Assertion failed in file ") + szFile + " at line " + szLine + "\n" + szDesc + sIgnore).c_str(), "Assertion failed", mode | MB_ICONINFORMATION) == IDNO)
            _CrtDbgBreak();
    }
}
#endif
```

Such cassert will make even debug builds run much faster because there is no actual call to (c)assert function, if condition is satisfied (and every such call would be quite heavy because of _CRT_STRINGIZE(#a) (condition as a string).

Answer (score 0):

There is no deactivation as for an assert, the condition will be tested all the time:

```
#if defined(__clang__) || defined(__GNUC__)
#define GSL_LIKELY(x) __builtin_expect(!!(x), 1)
#define GSL_UNLIKELY(x) __builtin_expect(!!(x), 0)
#else
#define GSL_LIKELY(x) (!!(x))
#define GSL_UNLIKELY(x) (!!(x))
#endif
```

And then yes, it throws an exception or even terminate depending on your settings:

```
#if defined(GSL_THROW_ON_CONTRACT_VIOLATION)

#define GSL_CONTRACT_CHECK(type, cond)                                                             \
    (GSL_LIKELY(cond) ? static_cast<void>(0)                                                       \
                      : gsl::details::throw_exception(gsl::fail_fast(                              \
                            "GSL: " type " failure at " __FILE__ ": " GSL_STRINGIFY(__LINE__))))

#elif defined(GSL_TERMINATE_ON_CONTRACT_VIOLATION)

#define GSL_CONTRACT_CHECK(type, cond)                                                             \
    (GSL_LIKELY(cond) ? static_cast<void>(0) : gsl::details::terminate())

#elif defined(GSL_UNENFORCED_ON_CONTRACT_VIOLATION)

#define GSL_CONTRACT_CHECK(type, cond) GSL_ASSUME(cond)

#endif // GSL_THROW_ON_CONTRACT_VIOLATION
```

If `GSL_UNENFORCED_ON_CONTRACT_VIOLATION` is set, nothing happens.